# How to capture rgb with depth as a photo in kinect 360 v.1 Ubuntu

Tags: kinect

I had installed kinect 360 in Ubuntu with freenect and processing P3 and working fine, I just want to know how to save from rgb and depth image to become color picture with depthmap (jpg, jpeg, png) in freenect and P3? (you can load as a 3d picture in Facebook). thanks

Comment: Please edit your question, it's unclear what are you asking.

Comment: I just want to save as video or photo (with depth), how to do that?